# tsql help on Running Total

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need t-sql help in generating running total. Here is sample data:

```
WITH SRC AS (
SELECT 0 AS A, 8.0 AS B,1 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3.0,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 7.0,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1.0,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5.0,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 6.0,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 4.0,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 3.0,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 9.0,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, NULL,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 10, NULL,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 5.0,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 2.0,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 8.0,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 14, NULL,4)
```

Using the above data i'm generating below columns including Running Total

```
 SELECT *
,(SUM(MAIN.B) OVER(PARTITION BY MAIN.E ORDER BY mAIN.a))Running_Total
 
FROM (
        SELECT * ,

        (case when c=1 then 1 else 0 end) as D ,

        (sum(case when C=1 then c end) over(order by A)) E FROM src
        )MAIN
```

Here is the Logic for Column D & E

```
Col D: is Generated based on Col:C if its 1 then 1 else its 0
Col E: is Sum of rows where Col: C is 1
```

The column Running Total is generated using sum for column: B using partitioning of Col: E.
Now i need another column: New_Total which is a kind of running total based on Col: B. Requirement  if the total exceeds 10 then retain the current row value. Here is the output i need

[image]

Please help in generating the result

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: its Azure SQl Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CASE logic to determine whether to SUM OVER or COALESCE either column E or the MAX OVER when using PARTITION BY column E.  Something like this

```
;WITH SRC AS (
    SELECT 0 AS A, 8.0 AS B,1 AS C UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 3.0,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 7.0,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,1.0,4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 5.0,5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 6.0,6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 4.0,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 3.0,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 9.0,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, NULL,4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, NULL,5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 5.0,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 2.0,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 8.0,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, NULL,4)
SELECT *,(SUM(MAIN.B) OVER(PARTITION BY MAIN.E ORDER BY mAIN.a)) Running_Total,
       case when (SUM(MAIN.B) OVER(PARTITION BY MAIN.E ORDER BY mAIN.a))>10 
                then coalesce(main.b, (max(MAIN.B) OVER(PARTITION BY MAIN.E ORDER BY mAIN.a)))
            else (SUM(MAIN.B) OVER(PARTITION BY MAIN.E ORDER BY mAIN.a)) end New_Total
FROM (SELECT *, (case when c=1 then 1 else 0 end) as D ,
                (sum(case when C=1 then c end) over (order by A)) E
      FROM src) MAIN;
```

```
A   B   C   D   E   Running_Total   New_Total
0   8.0 1   1   1   8.0             8.0
1   3.0 2   0   1   11.0            3.0
2   7.0 3   0   1   18.0            7.0
3   1.0 4   0   1   19.0            1.0
4   5.0 5   0   1   24.0            5.0
5   6.0 6   0   1   30.0            6.0
6   4.0 1   1   2   4.0             4.0
7   3.0 2   0   2   7.0             7.0
8   9.0 3   0   2   16.0            9.0
9   NULL    4   0   2   16.0        9.0
10  NULL    5   0   2   16.0        9.0
11  5.0 1   1   3   5.0             5.0
12  2.0 2   0   3   7.0             7.0
13  8.0 3   0   3   15.0            8.0
14  NULL    4   0   3   15.0        8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Derived table and return the output using your running total column. this can be done in first query as well.

```
 WITH SRC AS (
 SELECT 0 AS A, 8.0 AS B,1 AS C UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 3.0,2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 7.0,3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,1.0,4 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 5.0,5 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5, 6.0,6 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6, 4.0,1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7, 3.0,2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 8, 9.0,3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 9, NULL,4 UNION ALL
 SELECT 10, NULL,5 UNION ALL
 SELECT 11, 5.0,1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 12, 2.0,2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 13, 8.0,3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, NULL,4)

  SELECT 
   A.A
  ,CAST(A.B AS INT) AS B
  ,A.C
  ,A.D
  ,A.E
  ,CAST(A.[Running_Total] AS INT)  [Running_Total]
  , CASE WHEN Running_Total > 10  THEN ISNULL(CAST(A.[B] AS INT), (MAX(A.B) 
                    OVER(PARTITION BY A.E ORDER BY A.A)   ) )
        ELSE CAST(A.[Running_Total] AS INT) END AS [New_Total]      
  FROM 
  (

          SELECT *
           ,(SUM(MAIN.B) OVER(PARTITION BY MAIN.E ORDER BY MAIN.a))Running_Total

      FROM (
            SELECT * ,

            (CASE WHEN c=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D , 
            (sum(CASE WHEN C=1 THEN c END) OVER(ORDER  BY A)) E FROM src
             )MAIN

           ) AS A
```

[image: Result]